# Access parameters of JQuery object within onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble changing some legacy code. I have little to no experience with JQuery, I do with JavaScript.

The code is like the following:

```
(function($) {
    $.imgLoader= {
        isDebug: true,

        img: null,
        someText: null,

        /* example */
        testFunction: function(imgObject) {
            this.img = imgObject;
            // wait for the img to load
            this.img.onload = function() {
                // here I want to access the `someText` variable but this refers to `this.img.someText` instead of `this.someText`
                this.someText = 'someText'; 
            }
        };
}(jQuery));
```

As also described in the code above, I want to access the `someText` variable but this refers to `this.img.someText` instead of `this.someText`. Is there some way around this?

Preferably I'd even want to return a value from the `testFunction()` after the image has loaded.

Comment: Define a variable `self = this` in `testFunction`, then use it in `onload` function or use Arrow function i.e. `this.img.onload = () => {
                this.someText = 'someText'; 
            }`

Comment: @Satpal cool thanks that works. One more question, the `this.img.onload = () => { return true; }` for example doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?